# Is there a way to save both python stdout and stdin to file using only bash?

Tags: python, bash, file, stdout, stdin

There are shell shortcuts to save the python stdout to file like so:

```
python code.py > file
python code.py >> file
python code.py &> file
```

But this does not save the stdin that I type in through the terminal for in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Is there any way to save the text exactly like the terminal appears to us at the end of execution of a python script using only shell commands?

Comment: Perhaps this is what you're looking for: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html

Comment: what about sys.stdin , you can use in loop and read stdin and write stdout

Comment: @ReutSharabani My code requires me to `KeyboardInterrupt` out of the program and script didn't save to file. So I used the `-f` flag for flush. It saved successfully but only `cat typescript` gives proper result on terminal. The file, if opened with a text editor doesn't give utf-8 output (my terminal's encoding). There are hardcoded text elements for non printable characters (TAB, ESC etc.). How do I get utf-8?

Comment: @mithatkonuk I want all the `print` statements and the stderr statements if any along with my input too. I don't want to stdout every stderr statement.

Comment: Take a look at `script` command.

Comment: If `cat` gives the correct result and the text editor does not, then that must be the text editor at fault.  Change your text editor or look to see if there are display options for it.

Comment: @cdarke I have implemented my program and saved to typescript file. I am using gedit to open the file and I know I've set gedit up with default encoding as utf-8. I have attached the first few lines of my `typescript` file in the following comments

Comment: `gedit typescript`

Script started on Sunday 07 August 2016 01:55:10 PM IST
]0;hans@hans-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500: ~/Documents/MAC/SUCCESSFUL MODELS/ADD/Tensorflow with Eng and Tam Word2Vec[01;32mhans@hans-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500[00m:[01;34m~/Documents/MAC/SUCCESSFUL MODELS/ADD/Tensorflow w

ith Eng and Tam Word2Vec[00m$ script -h

Comment: `cat typescript`

Script started, file is typescript
hans@hans-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500:~/Documents/MAC/SUCCESSFUL MODELS/ADD/Tensorflow w
ith Eng and Tam Word2Vec$ python -m src.translate --data_dir /home/hans/Documents/MAC/SUCCESSFUL\ MODELS/ADD/Tensorflow\ with\ Eng\ and\ Tam\ Word2Vec/ --decode --train_dir /home/hans/Documents/MAC/SUCCESSFUL\ MODELS/ADD/Tensorflow\ with\ Eng\ and\ Tam\ Word2Vec/checkpoints/ --en_vocab_size=75000 --fr_vocab_size=50000 --size=325 --batch_size=32 --num_layers=3 --steps_per_checkpoint=500

Comment: When I used sublime text: `subl typescript`

Script started on Sunday 07 August 2016 01:55:10 PM IST
]0;hans@hans-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500: ~/Documents/MAC/SUCCESSFUL MODELS/ADD/Tensorflow with Eng and Tam Word2Vec[01;32mhans@hans-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500[00m:[01;34m~/Documents/MAC/SUCCESSFUL MODELS/ADD/Tensorflow w

ith Eng and Tam Word2Vec[00m$ script -h

Comment: Notice the extra characters? It's the same even if I use LibreOffice Writer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When `script` runs it captures terminal IO before the shell gets it (called non-canonical, or "raw" mode).  Normally the shell will interpret those characters or ignore them, but they are being shown in the editor.    So you need to sanitise the typescript file, and using `cat` is one way to do it.  I don't think this is a utf-8 issue, those are terminal control characters used by the shell.

Comment: So if `cat` is the only way to display the string and it will only display that output on the terminal, then is brute copy pasting the bash the only way to get document compatible text?

Ironically, I want it in document form for my college project report.

Comment: Is there a pythonic way to do save stdout and stdin in their order of display?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to record an interaction with the terminal you can use [script](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html):

> script makes a typescript of everything displayed on your terminal.
>   It is useful for students who need a hardcopy record of an
>   interactive session as proof of an assignment, as the typescript file 
>   can be printed out later with lpr(1).
>
> If the argument file is given, script saves the dialogue in this
>   file.  If no filename is given, the dialogue is saved in the file
>   typescript.

Answer (score 0):

You can save stdin to a variable, write this variable to your text file and then you can pass this variable to whatever programm you want to use it with.

```
read input
$input > textfile
$input | program
```

Comment: I want the stdout, stdin, and stderr outputs in a sequential manner, just as it appears in the execution of the code

Comment: so basically, you want a protocol of your terminal?